# Will the latest Bootstrap work properly with the default Wordpress jQuery?

Tags: jquery, templates, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

Wordpress still uses `jQuery 1.x` for fear of wrong compatibility with plugins and themes. They are trying to update it, but you can see that it will take a while yet (sources: [one](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37110), [two](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50564), [three](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/06/29/updating-jquery-version-shipped-with-wordpress/))

Now I am building a WP template where I have to use latest [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) CSS framework. The problem is that Bootstrap uses the latest `jQuery 3.5.1` !

So, will the latest Bootstrap work properly with the default Wordpress jQuery?

**Note: I understand that I can register the latest jQuery and unregister the old ones, but this is not recommended as other plugins may use the default WP jQuery**

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it works fine with BS4 - no conflicts, no issues.

Simple way to test is to install a vanilla WP 5.3.3, create a barebones theme with BS 4 and check the JS console for issues.